# Unable to display grids inside a responsive dialog using vaadin 14

Tags: vaadin-flow

I am trying to display grids that are in dialog but they only appear if we define a height like grid.setHeight(200px).
this is my code : https://gist.github.com/ust3000/b41c1c829e2e6d9a64b9e082bc150f5f
What is the right way to display grid inside Dialog and make the dialog responsive ?

```
public class TestPage extends HorizontalLayout {
public TestPage() {
    setJustifyContentMode(JustifyContentMode.CENTER);
    Grid<Row> grid1 = new Grid<>();
    Grid<Row> grid2 = new Grid<>();
    SplitLayout sp = new SplitLayout(grid1, grid2);
    sp.setOrientation(SplitLayout.Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
    // add column and populate grid1 and grid2
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
    dialog.add(sp);
    this.add(dialog);
    this.expand(dialog);
    dialog.open();
    this.setSizeFull();
  }
}
```

Comment: Paste your source code here rather than link.

Comment: i can not post my code here because i am getting this message :
It looks like your post is mostly code, please add some more details

Comment: I am having this same problem too. In particular, I can't get the grid to use 100% of the height of the dialog box....

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact version you are using?

I am running the `14.1.19` with your example and it works as expected :
[image]

But to your second question, the responsive API for the dialog comes with 14.2 version, but you can try it already now with the latest aplha : `14.2.0.apha9`:)

Comment: Is there any information available yet about how responsive support in Dialog will work under 14.2? @anasmi